# clean list and split into pairs

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have some objects in a list, here is a object class:

```
class MyData:
    def __init__(self, name, x1, y1, x2, y2): 
        self.name = name
        self.x1 = x1
        self.y1 = y1
        self.x2 = x2
        self.y2 = y2
```

Some objects in a list have a pairs by `obj.y2` but there is a tolerance `t = 10`. So `obj.y2 = 498` and `obj.y2 = 502` are pair because difference between these numbers is less then 10. Some object do not have a pair. So I need clean list with pairs only as output.

`[(obj,obj), (obj,obj),...]`  I was wondering to use itertools but can't construct logic. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) ?

> combinations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BC BD CD

in your case something like:

```
for x in itertools.combinations(yourlist, 2):
    // Pseudocode: your compare logic, something like if absolute(y2 - y1) < 10: 
    // then add to a different pair_only_list
```